# mod_rewrite not allowing access to an existing directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

Hello and thank you for taking the time to look this over.

I have rules set up in my .htaccess to create seo friendly urls. I use mysql and php to populate the content on each page which is all on index.php. The rule is set up to cover two levels of links, example.

mysite.com/first-level-link
mysite.com/first-level-link/second-level-link

The script is currently working perfectly on the front end of the website (all the webpages that are redirected to index.php). But I can not access the back end of the site which is located in a real directory on the server the path would look like this - mysite.com/admin/index.php

I have included two rules/conditions which should ignore the directories and files if they exist. I will include the code below:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `!-f` and `!-d` conditions only apply to the next `RewriteRule`, so your second rule doesn't have any conditions tied to it. You need to copy the conditions for that rule as well. The other problem is that the second rule is superceded by the first. Since `/some/path` matches `^(.*)$` before it gets a chance to match `^.*/(.*)$`, so you need to swap them around.

So all of your rules (starting from `RewriteEngine on`) will look like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```